# How do I delete a calendar/swipe lock-screen that appeared after Android 4.3 update?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, calendar

Recently, an Android 4.3 update appears to have created a strange and unwanted calendar/swipe lock-screen on my Galaxy S III which is pictured here.

The calendar provides an inaccurate date with a visible calendar event, and the `X... ...zZ` has to be swiped before I can get to my regular unlock pattern.  I am unable to get rid of this screen which pops up irregularly and is really annoying. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

<sup>(click image for a larger version)</sup>

Comment: Try checking you calender app's setting for an ability to disable intrusive activities... If not why not simply get an alternate calendar app? There are plenty of great calendar apps with better features and simplistic designs!

Comment: That is the S-Planner notification, i.e. the Samsung version of Google Calendar. Do you have an entry in it for this to go off every day? Have you cleared the data/cache and logged back in? Alternatively you could disable S-Planner and just download the official Google one, or many alternatives from the play store.